# Best way to check if one of the subelement is null and not throw an exception

Tags: c#

My call is for example:

```
var bankacc = workReport.works.customers.bankaccounts.Name;
```

that means that `works` can be null, `customers` can be null, `bankaccounts` can be also null. I don't want to check each of them if is null or not. Can I use some method to check the whole statement and if is null return back empty string?

EDIT:

I am using .NET FM 4.5

Comment: you might want to checkout the law of demeter.

Comment: Basically it's a bad idea to write this kind of code.

Comment: Note that ".NET 4.5" is irrelevant here - you're actually using "C# 5.0"

Comment: Why are `works`, `customers`, and `bankaccounts` all plural variable names, despite the fact that they appear to represent a single thing, rather than a collection of those things?

Comment: @Servy Entity Framework use plural

Comment: @senzacionale The names it uses are based (by default) on the names of the schema of your database; that's all.

Comment: yes exactly and EF use it in the same way so that way plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I'm not saying it's a good idea, but it's a possible solution** - extension methods.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static TResult IfNotNull<TSource, TResult>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> function)
        where TSource : class where TResult : class
    {
        if (source == null)
            return null;
        return function(source);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var bankacc = workReport.IfNotNull(x => x.works)
                        .IfNotNull(x => x.customers
                        .IfNotNull(x => x.bankaccounts
                        .IfNotNull(x => x.Name) ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: Good idea, but I am getting "can not convert null to TResult."

Comment: Added second generic constraint.

Comment: super, probably you save my day :D

Comment: This extension method is also present in the Microsoft Ajax Minifier library in case you happen to be using that (it's included by default in ASP.NET MVC projects).

Answer (score 2):

This is the [null-propogating](http://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/) syntax - an expected feature in the C# 6.0 specification (And out now if you want to use the VS 2015 Beta), but not one in current spec. Using the newer syntax of `?.`:

```
var bankacc = workReport?.works?.customers?.bankaccounts?.Name;
```

Your best bet using *current* spec (C# 5.0) is to instead use a series of variables and `if` statements which, while inelegant, is also what the compiler ends up doing under the hood for the `?.` operator.

It should also be noted that while possible, it is *not* advisable to use exceptions (ie a `catch { return null; }` statement) because Exceptions incur significant overhead (such as gathering the `StackTrace`)

Comment: @senzacionale The version of C# you are using and the version of .NET that you are using are two different things.  The most recent (non-beta) versions of each are C# 5.0 and .NET 4.5.  You can use C# 5.0 targeting .NET 2.0 if you want though.  C# is a language, .NET is just a library of code that can be used with that language.

Answer (score 1):

In the new and improved C# 6.0, you can do this with the [null conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx):

```
var bankacc = workReport?.works?.customers?.bankaccounts?.Name;

if (bankacc == null)
{
    // throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in the current version of C#. In the next version, you'll be able to do

```
var bankacc = workReport?.works?.customers?.bankaccounts?.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do a general "null" check across an expression in current C#.

However, you can explicitly catch the NullReferenceException it would generate:

```
string backacc;

try
{
   bankacc = workReport.works.customers.bankaccounts.Name;
}
catch (NullReferenceException nre)
{
   //Catching because I don't like if statements
   bankacc = String.Empty;
}
```

Not that this is a terribly *good* idea, but it avoids the multiple `if` statements as requested.

Comment: Using exceptions like that makes me feel bad.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Totally agree, I would just use the if statements. However, the OP said he didn't want to do that.

Comment: Boo for catching `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Like I said, not a good idea. I take it from you answer you don't have a better one that satisfies the requirements?

Comment: Nope, my answer is that there is no way to do that which satisfies the requirements. Your technique fails the implicit requirement of maintainability and also causes nausea in those who read the code later.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It seems maintainable to me, though there is certainly a change that I'm not thinking of. Agree on the nausea part though :)

Comment: To my mind, it's not maintainable if every maintainer has to look at it and say WTF?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Added comment to help with WTF. Its more maintainable than the massive ternary set though :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, however not recommended because it is hard to maintain. I would recommend BradleyDotNet's solution.

```
var bankacc = workReport == null ? string.Empty : workReport.works == null ? string.Empty : workReport.works.customers == null ? string.Empty : workReport.works.customers.bankaccounts == null ? string.Empty : workReport.works.customers.bankaccounts.Name;
```